# How do I save and exit a plist launchagent script from terminal

Tags: ios, macos, plist, daemon, launchd

I am a first time user for launchagent scripts on OSX.
Do you press '^E' to exit and save your plist launchagent script on OSX, because terminal only recognized this action as more code on my Mac.
I did create my plist script with `nano ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.testagent.plist` so the tui does come up and it does show that '^E' is to exit but once again, terminal only recognizes it as more text input for my script.
Thanks

Comment: What are you using to edit your plist?

Comment: I launched GNU nano within my terminal

Comment: ^ means control btw. So ^E means `Control + E`